# How to add text check in LoadRunner SAP GUI Protocol to validate sapgui_status_bar_get_text

Tags: java, loadrunner, sap-gui

See below code i got during the recording

```
sapgui_status_bar_get_text("paramStatusBarText", 
    BEGIN_OPTIONAL, 
        "Recorded status bar text: Transfer order 0126994069 created", 
        "AdditionalInfo=sapgui7032", 
    END_OPTIONAL);
```

Comment: Adding more tags related to your question might help people reach out to you faster. You can add up to 5 tags to your question

Answer (score 2):

I use C code as below:

```
int compare_results;


compare_results = strcmp(lr_eval_string("{MyParam}"),"<expected string>");

if( compare_results == 0 )
          lr_output_message("PASSED");
   else
         lr_error_message ("FAILED");
```